# OrientDB - out of memory

Tags: python, orientdb

I am trying to get all the nodes connected from a set of existing nodes:

```
SELECT outV().@rid FROM (SELECT EXPAND(inE("MyRelationship")) FROM 
  [#9:414449, #9:227196, #9:255662, #9:414441, #9:373179, #9:85859,
    #9:321781, #9:321785, #9:92176, #9:250499])
```

When I run this on the web interface, the results come in a few seconds. There are a lot of them. When I try running it via pyOrientDB I get this error:

```
File "myscript.py", line 127, in get_all_edges
    results = client.query(run_str, 500000)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyorient/orient.py", line 419, in query
    .prepare(( QUERY_SYNC, ) + args).send().fetch_response()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-    packages/pyorient/messages/commands.py", line 144, in fetch_response
    super( CommandMessage, self ).fetch_response()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-    packages/pyorient/messages/base.py", line 261, in fetch_response
    self._decode_all()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-    packages/pyorient/messages/base.py", line 245, in _decode_all
    self._decode_header()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-    packages/pyorient/messages/base.py", line 178, in _decode_header
    [ exception_message.decode( 'utf8' ) ]
pyorient.exceptions.PyOrientCommandException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError - GC overhead limit exceeded
```

I tried what is suggested elsewhere to add more memory by editing `server.sh` to add this to `exec "$JAVA":`

```
-Xmx64g -Dstorage.diskCache.bufferSize=16384
```

But no dice. Should I be editing another file? What can I do?

EDIT here are the last few lines from the log file:

```
2016-12-01T13:05:30.395-0800: 2442.304: #112: [Full GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 13875910K->13875910K(14913024K)] [ParOldGen: 44739580K->44739580K(44739584K)] 58615491K->58615491K(59652608K), [Metaspace: 24119K->24119K(26624K)], 8.3876841 secs] [Times: user=181.19 sys=0.19, real=8.38 secs] 
2016-12-01T13:05:38.784-0800: 2450.693: #113: [Full GC (Ergonomics) [PSYoungGen: 13875913K->13875910K(14913024K)] [ParOldGen: 44739583K->44739518K(44739584K)] 58615497K->58615428K(59652608K), [Metaspace: 24119K->24119K(26624K)], 66.1518818 secs] [Times: user=1465.07 sys=6.75, real=66.14 secs] 
2016-12-01T13:06:44.936-0800: 2516.845: #114: [Full GC (Ergonomics) [PSYoungGen: 13875913K->13875911K(14913024K)] [ParOldGen: 44739518K->44739518K(44739584K)] 58615432K->58615429K(59652608K), [Metaspace: 24120K->24120K(26624K)], 8.5330916 secs] [Times: user=183.20 sys=0.16, real=8.54 secs] 
2016-12-01T13:06:53.470-0800: 2525.379: #115: [Full GC (Ergonomics) [PSYoungGen: 13875913K->13875911K(14913024K)] [ParOldGen: 44739518K->44739517K(44739584K)] 58615432K->58615428K(59652608K), [Metaspace: 24122K->24122K(26624K)], 61.5085014 secs] [Times: user=1363.93 sys=5.96, real=61.50 secs] 
2016-12-01T13:07:54.979-0800: 2586.888: #116: [Full GC (Ergonomics) [PSYoungGen: 13875913K->13875912K(14913024K)] [ParOldGen: 44739517K->44739517K(44739584K)] 58615430K->58615430K(59652608K), [Metaspace: 24122K->24122K(26624K)], 8.3326564 secs] [Times: user=179.97 sys=0.18, real=8.33 secs] 
2016-12-01T13:08:03.312-0800: 2595.221: #117: [Full GC (Ergonomics) [PSYoungGen: 13875913K->13875913K(14913024K)] [ParOldGen: 44739517K->44739517K(44739584K)] 58615430K->58615430K(59652608K), [Metaspace: 24122K->24122K(26624K)], 8.3406577 secs] [Times: user=179.55 sys=0.18, real=8.34 secs] 
2016-12-01T13:08:11.653-0800: 2603.562: #118: [Full GC (Ergonomics) [PSYoungGen: 13875913K->13875913K(14913024K)] [ParOldGen: 44739517K->44739517K(44739584K)] 58615430K->58615430K(59652608K), [Metaspace: 24122K->24122K(26624K)], 8.3984178 secs] [Times: user=181.62 sys=0.16, real=8.40 secs] 
2016-12-01T13:08:20.053-0800: 2611.962: #119: [Full GC (Ergonomics) [PSYoungGen: 13875913K->13875913K(14913024K)] [ParOldGen: 44739521K->44739520K(44739584K)] 58615434K->58615433K(59652608K), [Metaspace: 24122K->24122K(26624K)], 57.3884980 secs] [Times: user=1270.66 sys=5.71, real=57.38 secs] 
2016-12-01T13:09:17.442-0800: 2669.351: #120: [Full GC (Ergonomics) [PSYoungGen: 13875913K->13813350K(14913024K)] [ParOldGen: 44739520K->44739507K(44739584K)] 58615434K->58552858K(59652608K), [Metaspace: 24124K->24124K(26624K)], 62.3461647 secs] [Times: user=1381.19 sys=6.25, real=62.33 secs] 
2016-12-01T13:10:19.789-0800: 2731.698: #121: [Full GC (Ergonomics) [PSYoungGen: 13813449K->13813350K(14913024K)] [ParOldGen: 44739507K->44739507K(44739584K)] 58552957K->58552858K(59652608K), [Metaspace: 24124K->24124K(26624K)], 8.4454292 secs] [Times: user=182.59 sys=0.18, real=8.45 secs] 
2016-12-01T13:10:28.235-0800: 2740.144: #122: [Full GC (Ergonomics) [PSYoungGen: 13813449K->13813351K(14913024K)] [ParOldGen: 44739507K->44739507K(44739584K)] 58552957K->58552859K(59652608K), [Metaspace: 24124K->24124K(26624K)], 8.3092564 secs] [Times: user=179.18 sys=0.20, real=8.31 secs] 
2016-12-01T13:10:36.545-0800: 2748.454: #123: [Full GC (Ergonomics) [PSYoungGen: 13813449K->0K(14913024K)] [ParOldGen: 44739507K->360347K(18045440K)] 58552957K->360347K(32958464K), [Metaspace: 24125K->24125K(26624K)], 3.5004088 secs] [Times: user=7.75 sys=2.57, real=3.50 secs]
```

And also in orient-server.log.0

```
Error on client connection
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Comment: http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Performance-Tuning.html :  For example if you can assign maximum 8GB to the Java process, it's usually better assigning small heap and large disk cache buffer (off-heap memory). So rather than:

```java -Xmx8g ...```
You could instead try this:

```java -Xmx800m -Dstorage.diskCache.bufferSize=7200 ...```

Comment: @OleksandrGubchenko for pyOrientDB do I modify `server.sh` or another file?

Comment: that's the correct file

Comment: How much ram do you have on system?

Comment: @IvanMainetti 512G

Comment: Please check the gclog when running the same select from Studio or from pyOrientDB, and verify if load and execution time is different . Restart the server for each test while using in JAVA_OPTS_SCRIPT the following options : -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintGCID -XX:+PrintGCDetails -Xloggc:$ORIENTDB_HOME/log/gc_%p_%t.log . You should be able to collect in log dir, 2 different gclog with pid and timestamp in file name. Compare behaviour and search "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError - GC overhead limit exceeded"  message.

Comment: You are using 16g for direct memory (e.g: for storage,wal http://orientdb.com/memory-consumed-by-orientdb/) and 64gb for java heap (e.g: for select), but it could be needed further tuning of parameters, with fixed generations, e.g :  (java 8) ORIENTDB_OPTS_MEMORY="-Xms64g -Xmn28m -Xmx64g -XX:MetaspaceSize=2g -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=2g -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:CompressedClassSpaceSize=1g"  or  ( java 7) ORIENTDB_OPTS_MEMORY="-Xms64g -Xmn28m -Xmx64g -XX:PermSize=2g -XX:MaxPermSize=2g -XX:+UseCompressedOops " . When you have found the correct values can add -XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy

Comment: @ClaudioMassi I added the log file you suggested to the question. Thanks for your help.